# Can not seem to change SSL cert on httpd server

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache

I am trying to setup SSL using httpd server. At  I created self cert and it worked fine, of course displaying brocker lock in browsers.

Now I got proper entrust cert but I can not seem to replace the old one. browser shows broken lock and when i open certificate info box it still does not show company name or proper server name, even though it has been changed.

how do you properly replace SSL certificate?

Comment: This is not related to programming, is it?

Comment: Have you changed it in the httpd.conf?